# Non-inferiority testing with coefficients and standard errors from ANOVA table in MLR?

Tags: multiple-regression

I'm examining the effect of 3 different interventions on a DV with age and gender included in my model.  Now, I'm curious as to whether I could apply the exact same analyses to test for non-inferiority?  Specifically, as I examine the ANOVA table, I am provided with the adjusted mean difference between Intervention2 and intervention1 (and Intervention3 and Intervention1 for that matter). Am I correct in thinking that I could use these differences + the standard errors (also in the ANOVA table) to construct 95% CI of the difference in the means (again, between I1 and I2 and I1 and I3) to test for non-inferiority after deciding upon a suitable non-inferiority threshold?